# Git: fatal: unable to access 'https://MY_REPO': Received HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: windows, git, proxy

I have a repository on our internal servers. If i try to pull/clone an existing repository i'm getting this error message.

But if i type this repo-link to Chrome, i can see my repository without any problem. We use corporate proxies and i've configurem them in ENV-Variable on windows and git global settings.

Git global settings:

```
http.sslverify=false
user.name=My name
user.email=myname@domain.com
http.proxy=http://PROXY:8080/
https.proxy=http://PROXY:8080/
```

Answer (score 4):

I should remove the proxy settings everywhere to connect my VPN. Because proxy server blocks my request because of non-existing server address.

Removing proxy for a local repository is also easy:

```
git config remote.origin.proxy ""
```